# Maximum Character allowed in Query string of WAF

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

Currently my WAF is blocking my query strings because of long query strings. Is there a way for WAF to allow long query strings? Otherwise what is the limit in characters that is allowed in the query string? If my query string is around 8k characters is it possible to have my WAF allow the query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure Application Gateway we have Maximum URL length limit 32KB.
Ref: [Application Gateway limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#application-gateway-limits)